# The server response was: 5.7.0 Too many messages in too short a time frame at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport

Tags: c#, smtpclient

I am developing one Windows Application sending bulk mails.
It worked successfully for 100 mails. After that it starts showing 
these errors

> The server response was: 5.7.0 Too many messages in too short a time frame  at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(
>   MailAddress sender,
>   MailAddressCollection recipients,
>   String deliveryNotify,
>   Boolean allowUnicode,
>   SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)
>      at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
>      at SmsAndEmail.Email.EmailIndex.SendTheMail()

This is my code:

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.From = new MailAddress("MailAddress");
msg.To.Add(mail.ToAddress);
msg.Subject = "MySub";
msg.Body = mail.EmailBody;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
client.Host = "hostname";
client.Port = 587;
client.EnableSsl = false;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("MailAddress", "password");
client.Timeout = 20000;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
  delegate(
    object s, 
    X509Certificate certificate,
    X509Chain chain, 
    SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors
  )
  { return true; }
;
try
{
    client.Send(msg);
    newStatus = "SUCCESS";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    newStatus = "Failed";
    errorMessage = "Mail Sending Failed !";
    return errorMessage;
}
```

Comment: What do you need to know? It's written right there in the error. Your mail server is throttled to allow only a certain number of e-mails within a specific time period. Make sure you're sticking to that limit and you'll be fine.

Comment: Improved some code formatting and error message formatting and added a relevant tag.